# Progressive Web App crashes on Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

Where I work we're currently making a PWA App. The app runs fine on Android, and on Desktop Chrome and Desktop Safari. Memory wise it takes between 16 to 18mb.

However on iOS, after loading too many images, the app crashes and the page reloads. I've already tried to search for anwsers. I tried to cache the images by creating an URL from a blob to try to reduce duplicates, but the app still crashes. (These images are treated diferently from the main cache. They don't need to be available offline) Not only that but it seems that the page ocupies more memory than it does on Android - on my iPhone it says 38mb.

All of these images are obtained from Ajax requests and then some of them are shown in a scrollable list, while others are shown in a different context.

I've already read that Mobile Safari has a 10mb limit on the whole page. Our app is made of only one webpage divided into sections, and it is is being created with jQuery Mobile with most of its content being dynamically generated.

Did any of you had similar problems, and if so, how did you work them out?

Comment: I know this was asked a while ago but we are experiencing similiar issues with taking photos and pwa crashing after a while of use.  did you ever figure this out?

Comment: How did you get memory consumption?